# What to use to replace appsettings.json in C#.NET 6.0 AWS Lambda Function?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am developing AWS Lambda (NET6) function.
Now it uses appsettings.json file for RDS connection string and some other config parameters.
What in AWS can be used as a replacement for appsetings: AWS Parameter store, AWS SystemsManager etc?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AWS Systems Manager Parameter Store is an alternative to the `appsettings.json` file as it allows you to save data in a **hierarchical order**. In the .NET application, the `ConfigurationBuilder` is commonly used to initialize the values from the `appsettings.json` file into the application.

Similarly, if you use [Amazon.Extensions.Configuration.SystemsManager](https://github.com/aws/aws-dotnet-extensions-configuration/) NuGet package, it helps to initialize your app-settings details from the SSM parameter store into the lambda function. IMO, It's the best alternative, as it requires only minimum code changes on your end.

Here's an example of how to use it:

```
IConfiguration configurations = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                        .AddSystemsManager("/you-can-also-add-some-more-prefixes-separated-with-forward-slash-if-you-want/your-lambda-function-name/")
                        .Build();
```

The mentioned SSM path in the configuration will load all the child elements underneath it into the `IConfiguration`. As a result, you can use `IConfiguration` to read your configuration details that are stored in the SSM parameter store, just like how you read values from `appsettings.json` file.

Note that to save database credentials or any other sensitive information in the SSM parameter store, use the parameter type as a `secure string`.

You can also consider using the Secrets Manager to manage your RDS credentials, and it will help to rotate your DB credentials periodically.

Edit:

For instance, if you have your `appsettings.json` file structured as you mentioned in the comment section:

```
{
   "Swagger": { "Enabled": true }
}
```

Then create an SSM parameter path as shown below and set its value to `true`:

```
/you-can-also-add-some-more-prefixes-separated-with-forward-slash-if-you-want/your-lambda-function-name/Swagger/Enabled
```

If you've configured the SSM parameters to mirror the structure of the appsettings file, your remaining code should work without any code changes.

Comment: Am I correct: I add the code (above) and the rest of code works fine for SSM and for appsettings.json if no this code added?

Comment: How to create the same hierarchy in AWS Parameters Store as in appsettings.json?

Comment: How to store in PS this piece of appsettings.json:  "Swagger": {
        "Enabled": true
    }, ?

Comment: Updated the answer, please check it out.

Comment: ok,  I see. Yet qstn:  the path can contain any parts but not lambda-fun-name? I want to use one parameter set for lambda functions set. And about value true  - PS does not allow boolean? what to use: string?

Comment: yes, you can use any path segments but make sure to use the same in the configuration section. And, you have to use a string to represent the boolean value in the SSM parameter store.

Comment: To be exact: we cannot keep the same code working with appsettings.json and AWS PS. In some cases need to add piece of code to convert strings to bool, int as in this example with Swagger/Enabled

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned, you need AWS Services to store Credentials and secrets that can be used in the Lambda function.

There are tools that can be used for the same purpose. Here are some:

1. [AWS Systems Manager Parameter Store](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/systems-manager-parameter-store.html)

To use Parameter Store:

- Store your configuration parameters in Parameter Store.
- Configure your Lambda function to retrieve these parameters at runtime using the AWS SDK or AWS SDK for .NET.

This approach provides better security since you can leverage encryption and fine-grained access control over your parameters.

2. [AWS Secrets Manager](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/secretsmanager/latest/userguide/intro.html)

To use Secrets Manager:

- Store your sensitive configuration information as secrets in Secrets Manager.
- Configure your Lambda function to retrieve secrets from Secrets Manager at runtime using the AWS SDK or AWS SDK for .NET.

Secrets Manager provides an additional layer of security, particularly suited for sensitive data.

3. Environment Variables (Lambda's ENV)

Comment: How to do "Store your configuration parameters in Parameter Store" and store the same hierarchy as in appsettings.json to have the same code for retrieving?